# Asp.Net Web Forms: Render specific text throughout the application differently

Tags: asp.net, localization, rendering

Let's say I have the following text on one of my web pages (which offers localized content through local resource files):

"Your **xyzProductname** was developed on the principles of intensive research."

Localized to German, this would mean something like:

"Ihr **xyzProductname** wurde auf Basis von intensiven Forschungen entwickelt."

What I want to achieve now is that the "xyzProductname" is rendered differently than the rest of the text throughout the application. So whenever this specific text appears, it has to be rendered **automatically** using a predefined CssClass. 
I cannot just set the CssClass of each occurence of the product name manually because the product name appears more often in certain localized versions.

Any pointers to a solution are appreciated!

Comment: Is xyzProductName always rendered using the same type of control (asp:Literal, asp:Label, etc)?

Comment: Yes and no. Currently it is just within div's and sometimes within labels. Where's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you cannot have mixed formatting within certain controls. So for instance if this control was rendered as a span you cannot have this one word rendered differently to all of the other text, you would instead need to wrap this one word in it's own tag.

e.g.
`<span>Your xyzProductname was developed on the principles of intensive research</span>`

Cannot have the formatting you want. Instead you would have to do this:

`<span>Your </span><span>xyzProductname </span><span>was developed on the principles of intensive research</span>`

This is so that a CSS rule can be applied to the second span. If this was not considered at the start then you will have to go back through and alter the controls to allow this to happen.

This will all depend on what kind of controls you want this done to, buttons, textboxes, labels etc. all require different approaches to get the same effect.

Comment: The problem is that those product names are retrieved from the localization resource file; so I can't put them into a span. 
Or can I put the <span> tags into the resource file as well?

Comment: AFAIK you can put the spans into the resource file but I am not completely sure about that. You will need to set a css class for the span you want to format differently and then set the properties for the css class.

Comment: I tried that now and it works. 
I consider it a dirty solution since it complicates the localization process but I guess I'll have to go along with it, thanks!

Comment: Yes I agree it is quite a dirty solution. Hopefully I have steered you right and it is the least dirty though :)